# Creating modules in maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have created this maven subproject that willcontain the domain objects of the project:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.platsbruts</groupId>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>model</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>platsbruts model</description>
```

and in this other project I will use the domain objects defined before:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.platsbruts</groupId>
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>platsbrutsBackend</name>
<description>platsbruts Backend</description>
```

but when I do a

```
import com.platsbruts.backend.domain.User;
```

I got the error: `cannot resolve symbol domain`

Comment: `<parent/>` is parent ..and `<dependency/>` is dependency(!), you seem to mix up concepts: +1 for rmalchow's answer! ..and [further reading](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two problems: for one, a "pom" module cannot contain any classes. only "jar" packaged modules can. second (and kind of related), you do can NOT inherit classes from the parent pom. you can only inherit dependencies.

what you should probably do is this:

```
com.platsbruts:foo
    packaging: POM
    modules:
    - com.platsbruts:foo-model
         packaging: JAR
    - com.platsbruts: foo-impl
         packaging: JAR
         dependency: com.platsbruts:foo-model
```

this should do the trick